# NUNIT test cases for adding and deleting a table with many to many relationship in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many, nunit

I have a table like

```
Class Author{
int AuthorId;
string Nmae;
}
Class book {
int bookid;
Author Author;
}
```

And now I am going to add a new entry to the book.

If I add `book.Author.Add(newAuthor)`, will the `newAuthor` automatically get added to `Authors` table?

Or should I write this instead?

```
dbcontext.Author.Add(author)
```

along with

```
book.Author.Add(newAuthor)
```

When I am running unit tests, it errors with `Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store`.

Once I wrote `dbcontext.Author.Add(author)` and there was no error.

The other method I tried was in `[SetUp]` where I added an author in the `Authors` table. Then, I added this author to the `books` table. But then I got

> The instance of entity type 'Author' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'AuthorId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

The instance of entity type 'Member' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay to update.
I got the problem rectified.
Class Author
{ int AuthorId; 
string Nmae; } 
Class book
{ int bookid; 
Author Author; }

before I added dbcontext.Books.Add(book)

I added dbcontext.Author.Add(newauthor)

and it worked fine without creating any additional entry, since it was having only Id as the foreign key and author entity is not added as it is as a relational entity.